# Get computer information using a bootloader

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader, system-information

I'm researching about OS developing and I'd like to know how to get computer information like, motherboard model, HDD size, processor speed, etc.

Maybe there are some BIOS interrupts I could use, but I couldn't find anyone.

PD: There is no OS, I should be able to obtain this info from a bootloader written in NASM.

Comment: See [smbios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) and [dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode). For disk information, see `int 13/48` or low level ATA commands. For memory, use `int 15/E820`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that.